# Form validation with numeric rules

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation

I'm trying to validate input field in Magento 2. I have added js to same page, so validation like this `data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"` works.

But how to validate `min_text_length` or `max-words` or something that requires number, not just true or false?

This is how I tried but it does not work.

```
<input value="Name" name="first_name" id="first_name_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'min_text_length':'20'}" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug of Magento 2. I'm currently on Magento CE 2.1.7 and this bug is not fixed, and the solution is exactly in this discussion:

[Magento 2 minimum length validation is not working for text field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157714/magento-2-minimum-length-validation-is-not-working-for-text-field/164689)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

Only added `'validate-length':true` in the tag.

```
<input value="Name" name="first_name" id="first_name_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true,'validate-length':true, 'min_text_length':'20'}" type="text">
```

OR

```
<input value="Name" name="first_name" id="first_name_field" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-length':true}" class="validate-length minimum-length-[0-9]+$ maximum-length-[0-9]+$ input-text" type="text" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work